# NSNotification keyBoardWillShow and keyboardWillHide are not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikeyboard, nsnotification

I have a xib file with custom view on which I have many textfields subviews. I have set delegates on each of the textfield to the file owner and successfully able to texfield delegate methods. But unfortunately the keyboard notification methods keyboardWillShow: and keyboardWillHide: not being called at all.

I added observers at textfieldShouldBeginEditing and removed the observers at textFieldDidEndEditing.

Here is the snippet of my code:

Adding Observer

```
-(void) textFieldShouldBeginEditing : (UITextField *) textField{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
}
```

Removing observer

```
-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing : (UITextField *) textField{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}
```

//Methods for notification

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
NSLog(@"Here");
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
NSLog(@"There");
}
```

//Any of those keyboardwillShow and keyboardWillHide is not called.

It will be great if someone can help me figure out the issue with my code or any underlaying issue which I may be missing.

Comment: It's possible that the keyboard shows before `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` gets called which causes `keyboardWillShow` to never be called. Start observing earlier and see if that changes anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding an observer when you are showing keyboard by editing textView. It won't call because keyboard is already shown. You should add observers on your `viewWillAppear` and remove `viewWillDisappear` methods.

Comment: I added observer on keyboardShouldBeginEditing. Sorry, I said didBeginEditing. Also, it is only a xib file and the viewcontroller instantiates other views based on xib name and same xib may not be instantiated in it's parent viewcontroller

Comment: Add it before in `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: I only have awakeFromNib method

Comment: Yup it will do. But it is better to add this observers in a viewController where you are using your xib on these two lifecycle methods.

Comment: I will try to implement it in awakeFromNib and will let you know if it works. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, adding observer at awakeFromNib did not work. :(

Comment: You've added will `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];` still with no success? Then I suggest implementing these two observers as I said in controller where you use your xib.

Comment: Yep.`-(void)awakeFromNib{
    [super awakeFromNib];
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
}`

Comment: So I suggest ditching out these textView delegate methods and implementing observers in controller.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot do that in viewcontroller because the viewcontroller instantiates different view based on the enumeration value it receives and most the views have their own NSNotificationCenter, so that approach is not suitable for me. I have to figure out the NSNotification. Please inform me if you could figure out the error for me. Thanks